# Crear objeto java a partir de API Rest y okhttp en ANDROID

Tags: java, android, rest

Estoy intentando acceder a mi API REST para obtener un JSON con los datos de un objeto. Luego quiero convertir ese JSON al objeto en Java, pero no lo estoy consiguiendo.

Este es el objeto Usuario que tengo en mi proyecto

```
package com.example.weruleapp.Modelo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Usuario {

    private String Nombre;
    private String Email;
    private String Apellido1;
    private String Apellido2;
    private int Tipo;
    private String Funcion;
    private String Provincia;
    private String Categoria;
    private String Dni;
    private String Federacion;
    private int LastTimeSeen;
    private String PaginaActiva;
    private ArrayList<TestFinalizado> TestFinalizados;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getApellido1() {
        return Apellido1;
    }

    public void setApellido1(String apellido1) {
        Apellido1 = apellido1;
    }

    public String getApellido2() {
        return Apellido2;
    }

    public void setApellido2(String apellido2) {
        Apellido2 = apellido2;
    }

    public int getTipo() {
        return Tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(int tipo) {
        Tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getFuncion() {
        return Funcion;
    }

    public void setFuncion(String funcion) {
        Funcion = funcion;
    }

    public String getProvincia() {
        return Provincia;
    }

    public void setProvincia(String provincia) {
        Provincia = provincia;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return Categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        Categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return Dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        Dni = dni;
    }

    public String getFederacion() {
        return Federacion;
    }

    public void setFederacion(String federacion) {
        Federacion = federacion;
    }

    public int getLastTimeSeen() {
        return LastTimeSeen;
    }

    public void setLastTimeSeen(int lastTimeSeen) {
        LastTimeSeen = lastTimeSeen;
    }

    public String getPaginaActiva() {
        return PaginaActiva;
    }

    public void setPaginaActiva(String paginaActiva) {
        PaginaActiva = paginaActiva;
    }

}
```

Mi idea es consumir de una API que ya tengo creada en un servidor web, y guardar ese JSON con los datos. En postman, al hacer la petición, recibo un JSON correctamente.

En la activity de java, estoy haciendo la siguiente llamada al controlador de usuario:

```
Usuario user = new UsuarioController().generateUsuario(email);
```

y en el controlador tengo el siguiente código:

```
package com.example.weruleapp.Controlador;

import com.example.weruleapp.Modelo.Usuario;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

import android.util.Log;

public class UsuarioController {

    public Usuario generateUsuario(String Email){
        //TODO Access API Rest to get data and create Usuario Object.
        String url_Login = "http://10.0.2.2/API/usuario/read_one.php?usuario="+Email;
        OkHttpClient okhttpclient = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url_Login)
                .build();
        Response response = null;
        try{
            response = okhttpclient.newCall(request).execute();
            String respuesta = response.body().string();
            Log.d("response",respuesta);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //TODO Una vez obtenido el JSON usar setters sobre el usuario
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        return usuario;
    }
}
```

El Log no está imprimiendo nada, y en el Logcat de Android Studio estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

[image]

La línea 21 del Controlador es la siguiente:

```
response = okhttpclient.newCall(request).execute();
```

Básicamente no estoy consiguiendo descargar los datos de la API.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucedes es que no puedes retornar el objeto en el metodo que hace la peticion HTTP, Por que? porque `okhttp` se ejecuta de forma asincrona, es decir se completa hasta que obtiene un respuesta del servidor y la respuesta puede variar debido a muchas cosas asi que debes validar lo que obtienes.

Aqui un ejemplo de uso de okhttp:

```
OkHttpClient cliente = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
public static final MediaType JSONS
        = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

private void getUsuario(String Email) throws JSONException {
    String url_Login = "http://10.0.2.2/API/usuario/read_one.php?usuario="+Email;
        final okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url(url_Login)
                .get()
                .build();
        try {
            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Log.i("Error", "*******error****");
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) { // si la respuesta es de exito si no ingresa a este bloque
                        final String respuestaServer = response.body().string();
                        SincronizarActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject respuesta = new JSONObject(respuestaServer);
                                    generateUsuario(respuesta);// cuando obtienes la respuesta del servidor puedes ejecutar el metodo que te retorne el objeto que quieres.

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.i("Error1****", e.getMessage());
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }                    
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Error2****", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
private Usuario generateUsuario(JSONObject respuesta) {
    Log.i("***log",respuesta.toString());
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Pero no puedo ejecutar en UiThread porque el controlador no es una vista. Es una clase que hay por detrás...

Comment: entonces pasale la actividad al metodo getUsuario(Activity activity, String Email)